# Youtube Data API Limit requests

Tags: api, video

I'm working with an academic researcher on a project that involves sending a large volume of requests to the  [Youtube Data AAPI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3). The problem we've encountered is that the 10,000 unit daily request limit is too small for our research project. We've tried submitting requests for a rate increase via Youtube's web form but the questions and material they expect are focused on commercial applications and usage of the API. The requests we've submitted so far have either been ignored or received automated responses for being incomplete.

Does anyone have experience accessing Youtube metadata for academic research? Is there a better way to request a rate limit increase for the Youtube API for a research project? Does anyone have any guidance about the type of material needed to get a response from the Youtube team?

Comment: i got the same problem, did you find an answser ? Thanks, Pierre

Comment: perhaps a duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/18549/1511

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve the problem? Has youtube replied to you? Can you tell us about your experience?