# Index of YouTube video titles

Tags: nlp, text, video

I'm looking for a way to identify (as many as possible) YouTube videos on a certain topics based on a keywords occurring in their titles.

YouTube Data API provides a way to search for videos based on the keywords but [limits results up to 500 titles only](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

[Common Crawl](https://commoncrawl.org/) indexes YouTube.com domain but it contains information only about page URLs and not its HTML `<title>` while YouTube.com videos do not have their titles in URL (basicaly it's `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v01QZUxYg62`).

There's [YouTube 8M dataset](http://research.google.com/youtube8m/) of segmented videos but it seems an overkill to just get the titles. Is there any other corpora of up-to-date YouTube video titles?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) to make queries, and then dump just the metadata as a json, without downloading the video. Then you can parse the (huge) json to get just the ids and titles and categories, or any other field with **[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)**

```
youtube-dl --no-warnings --dump-single-json "ytsearch1:mike birbiglia it's so easy to be on time" | jq -r '.entries[] | "\(.id)\t\(.title)\t\(.categories)"'
```

returns tab-separated id, title, categories

```
W-_M4r-gKI0 Mike Birbiglia - It's So Easy To Be On Time ["Comedy"]
```

my sources: [metadata + jq](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/23442#issuecomment-566746924) and [ytsearch](https://askubuntu.com/a/906363/104223)

fyi, the link you shared wasn't available for me

btw, it's a funny video

Comment: Thanks. To get more results, e.g., 100, use `ytsearch10:Obama`

Comment: And the link to YouTube video I've provided is fake.